# How do I verify that a relay is working with IPv6?

Tags: relays, ipv6

After upgrading to Tor 0.2.4.19 I configured a relay to support IPv6. I was a bit surprised to see nothing regarding IPv6 in the logs at startup, but I can see that Tor is binding to the configured IPv6 ports. As I don't see connections being made to Tor over IPv6, how can I verify that the relay is working with IPv6?

Is there some kind of relay overview which shows IPv6-enabled relays?

Comment: First, is it a relay or bridge? If it's a relay then you are most likely one of only a handful of people using IPv6 internally. If its a bridge then most likely no one with IPv6 knows of your bridge to connect to it.

Comment: It's a relay. I'm aware that there isn't already much IPv6 adoption in the Tor network, but I'm still searching for a way to verify that the relay is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The following graph shows you which version relays are running:

[image: Relay versions between september and December 2013]

As you can see most relays were running Tor 0.2.3 and somewhen in the middle of December 2013 they started to upgrade. Tor started to support IPv6 exits with version 0.2.4.8-alpha (see [#5547](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/5547)). So most of the running relays are not able to exit to IPv6 addresses even if they have the underlying network. This might improve as more and more upgrade to the recent 0.2.4 series.

I tried to find some other IPv6 exits using [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) and [Torstatus](http://torstatus.info/), but couldn't find any.  It seems that the sites do not support it at the moment. However I also asked in the Tor chat (#tor on OFTC). I was pointed to `cached-microdescs`. They contain at the moment nearly 250 Tor relays, ca. 30 are exits.

So you can set `ClientUseIPv6 1` in your `torrc` and go to `ipv6.google.com.YOURRELAY.exit` (YOURRELAY should be the name or fingerprint of your exit). That way you might be able to see if some traffic exits on your relay or if there are problems.

In the case of a non-exit relay you can additionally do the following:

1. Set `EntryNodes YOURRELAY` in your `torrc`. The value of `YOURRELAY` should be the name or fingerprint of you relay.
2. Set `StrictNodes 1`. This ensures that only you relay will be used.
3. Restart Tor.
4. Try a view websites and have a look at your relay.

Comment: As the relay I'm running is no exit relay, I doubt your suggested procedure won't work.